# Javascript popup when idle, only after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a popup when a user is idle for (x) seconds and the idle timer only starts after a button is clicked but the timer is reset if there is mouse movement or another click. I also want this popup to only occur 1 timer per session.

So far I have the function working when the button is clicked and the popup shows up after 3 seconds. I would like the timer to be able to be reset when the mouse moves or is clicked.

Here's my javascript

```
function idlePop() {
            var timer = 3000;

            function resetTimer() {
                
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                if (!sessionStorage.getItem('popupPreviouslyShown') || false) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#donate-overlay').css('display', 'block');
                        sessionStorage.setItem('popupPreviouslyShown', true);
                    }, timer);
                }
            });
        }
```

And the html button if you wanted to see it

```
<button onclick="idlePop();">Start</button>
```

I'm getting choked up on the function to reset the timer on mouse move (onmousemove) and on mouse click. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: the process is not very clear...

Comment: @Frenchy how can I explain more? I want a popup when idle for 3 seconds. If a user is moving their mouse or clicking, I want the timer to reset. I only want this timer to begin after the button is pressed (not on page load).

Comment: i propose a solution, but following what i have understoos...

Answer (score 0):

i propose a solution , we'll see with what you say:

i suggest you to replace

```
<button onclick="idlePop();">Start</button>
```

by

```
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

user clicks on start button and after an idle of 3sec the popup appears

**UPDATED V1.0**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stage = 0;
  var timer = 3000;
  var timout = -1;
  var isDetectionActivated = false;


  $("#start").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#start").prop("disabled", true);
    //e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("start");
    idlePop();
  })

  function activateDetection() {
    isDetectionActivated = true;
    $(document).on("mousemove click", function(e) {
      console.log("timeout aborted")
      // you couldt test the type of event with e.type
      clearTimeout(timout);
      //console.log("you have moved or clicked", e.type);
      //re-launch process
      idlePop();

    });
  }

  function desactivateDetection() {
    $(document).off("mousemove click");
    isDetectionActivated = false;
  }

  function idlePop() {
    console.log("idlePop");

    //for debuging
    /*
    timout = launchTimeout(timer);
    return;
    */

    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('popupPreviouslyShown') || false) {
      timout = launchTimeout(timer);
    }
  }

  function launchPopup() {
    console.log("popup");
    $('#donate-overlay').css('display', 'block');
    sessionStorage.setItem('popupPreviouslyShown', true);
  }

  function launchTimeout() {
    if (!isDetectionActivated) {
      activateDetection();
    }
    console.log("timeout activated");
    return setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("timeout finished");
      $("#start").prop("disabled", false);
      clearTimeout(timout);
      desactivateDetection();
      launchPopup();

    }, timer);

  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, however this is not the solution. I guess another way to explain what I'm trying to achieve is a function will run that will start a timeout timer. After 3 seconds of being idle (i.e. no mouse movement or clicks) a popup will appear. The timer should only start counting down when idle.

Comment: ok do the first thing,  the session loads, if user is idle during 3sec, it could click on button and the popup appears after 3sec?

Comment: Not quite, I dont want this to happen with page load, I want it to be onclick. Idle countdown timer begins onclick **but** if the user moves mouse or clicks, the countdown timer will reset so that **only** 3s of idle time will the popup appear.

Comment: @briannelson95 ok i have done this part, so when the user click , after idle of 3sec,  the popup is launched